# Laravel Query Builder doesn't identify variable as integer and adds quotation marks

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

when I try to run:

```
$alunos = DB::table('students')
    ->select('students.id','students.name','students.matricula','students.birth')
    ->join('horarios_has_students','horarios_id','=',DB::Raw($id))
    ->whereRaw('students.id = horarios_has_students.students_id')
    ->where('students.situation',1)
    ->orderBy('students.name', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

And It works just fine. But if I change DB::Raw($id) for just $id,
like this:

```
... 
->join('horarios_has_students','horarios_id','=',$id)
...
```

It doesn't work because in this case horarios_id is a foreign key and Laravel add quotations marks (the ones used in MySQL queries). So I get this error message:

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '3' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `students`.`id`, `students`.`name`, `students`.`matricula`, `students`.`birth` from `students` inner join `horarios_has_students` on `horarios_id` = `3` where students.id = horarios_has_students.students_id and `students\`.`situation` = 1 order by `alunos`.`name` asc) "

With DB::Raw() works because it removes the ``, so this would work just if the command was ...
on `horarios_id` = 3 
...
What should I do to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the table to join on the function, never put only "id" becase your tables can have mutiple of them:

    `->join('table','table_join.id,'=', table.id)`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$alunos = DB::table('students')
    ->select('students.id', 'students.name', 'students.matricula', 'students.birth')
    ->join('students.id', 'horarios_has_students.students_id')
    ->where('horarios_has_students.horarios_id', $id)
    ->where('students.situation', 1)
    ->orderBy('students.name', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answer?